# How to untangle spring for kitchen faucet hose?

Tags: kitchens, sink

I'm trying to install a Grohe Concetto kitchen faucet with a spray hose.  There is a long spring that is put over the hose in order to create the tension needed to help the hose return after it has been extended.  The instructions are mediocre at best and I found a better illustration in [an older set of instructions on-line](http://s2.img-b.com/build.com/mediabase/specifications/1315663.pdf).  As I pulled the spring off of the hose, it got away from me and managed to tangle in one spot and I cannot figure out how to untangle this.  The ends of the spring are attached to plastic rings so the ends aren't open.  Essentially a long closed-end slinky.

Help...I feel like I've created the new Rubik's Cube.
[image: Grohe 07240000 Part- Ladylux Spring - tangled]

[Here's a link to the part listing with a picture of the spring part compressed.](http://www.guillens.com/index.jsp?path=product&part=111281)

Comment: The upper half has to be pushed down below the lower half. Try it as it is configured now (as it appears in the picture). If that doesn't work, rotate the upper half 90 degrees clockwise and try again.

Comment: Rotate both of the ends your holding, top sides coming together, simultaneously. This will *un-keychain* the spring from itself, eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't untangle it easily while the hose is in place.

If you can remove the hose, this becomes straightforward; rotate the sections of spring 90 degrees to each other, and it should become obvious that pushing one through the other will either disengage them or make the problem worse. If it looks like it will make the problem worse, rotate one side 180 degrees and look again. If that still doesn't look like it will help, rotate back the other way. Stretch the two sections so the space between the wires is the diameter of the spring while doing this so it can be pulled through.

Websearching "untangling a spring" or "untangling a slinky" will find illustrations/videos that will help you with this. From what you've shown us, it looks like there's just a single crossing that needs to be backed out.

Then reinstall the hose and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately was difficult enough that after about 90 minutes I simply decided to order a new spring and install it very carefully.  Perhaps it was possible but it only seemed to get worse when we tried.

Answer (score 0):

We untangled our hose by holding the loop and shaking it continually with the two ends facing the floor.

It wasn't on the cardboard tube.