# Spring for kitchen faucet

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I have a Grohe kitchen faucet that has a weak spring. Without disassemble the faucet is there any way to tightening the spring so it retracts tight.

Comment: Welcome! We need more information to understand the issue, please. What model faucet? Which spring do you mean, or do you perhaps mean a sprayer end retracting fully into its base? Photos would likely be helpful as well.

Comment: This related question may be helpful: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/46194/how-to-untangle-spring-for-kitchen-faucet-hose

Comment: Are you talking about a pullout head not retracting well? Check underneath for obstructions.